# Is there a way to subset data by keeping the first observation of one condition and the previous observation prior to the onset of a condition?

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataset that contains multiple observations per individual and observations were taken yearly. There are 2 conditions (TRUE or FALSE). Some individuals have multiple observations per condition, others have multiple observations for only 1 condition:

```
ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)
Cond = c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)
date = as.Date(c("2017-05-02", "2018-07-04", "2019-06-18","2011-05-05", "2012-08-09", "2015-06-13", "2016-02-08", "2017-07-22", "2014-05-03", "2015-09-05", "2016-04-07", "2016-03-06", "2017-07-23", "2018-09-28", "2019-05-29"))
df = data.frame(ID, Cond, date)
```

Which then looks like this:

```
   ID  Cond       date
1   1 FALSE 2017-05-02
2   1  TRUE 2018-07-04
3   1  TRUE 2019-06-18
4   2 FALSE 2011-05-05
5   2 FALSE 2012-08-09
6   3 FALSE 2015-06-13
7   3 FALSE 2016-02-08
8   3  TRUE 2017-07-22
9   4 FALSE 2014-05-03
10  4 FALSE 2015-09-05
11  4 FALSE 2016-04-07
12  5 FALSE 2016-03-06
13  5 FALSE 2017-07-23
14  5  TRUE 2018-09-28
15  5  TRUE 2019-05-29
```

I want to subset the data so that each individual has one row for the last observation where the condition was FALSE and a second row for the first observation where the condition is TRUE, excluding all individuals who only have observations for one condition. The above example would then look like:

```
  ID  Cond       date
1  1 FALSE 2017-05-02
2  1  TRUE 2018-07-04
3  3 FALSE 2016-02-08
4  3  TRUE 2017-07-22
5  5 FALSE 2017-07-23
6  5  TRUE 2018-09-28
```

I'm just not sure on how to do this with a large dataset.

Comment: From my limited exposure, I guess this is about the R language and I edited the tags accordingly. Is that correct? In the future please at least tag your question with the language you ask about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is likely a better way, but here is one approach using `dplyr`. First, `group_by` each `ID` and then use `slice` for obtain the last `Cond` which is `FALSE` using `tail`, and the first `Cond` which is `TRUE` using `head`. Finally, only include results where there are two rows for a given `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(c(tail(which(!Cond), 1), head(which(Cond), 1))) %>%
  filter(n() == 2)
```

**Output**

```
     ID Cond  date      
  <dbl> <lgl> <date>    
1     1 FALSE 2017-05-02
2     1 TRUE  2018-07-04
3     3 FALSE 2016-02-08
4     3 TRUE  2017-07-22
5     5 FALSE 2017-07-23
6     5 TRUE  2018-09-28
```

Comment: Thanks - I edited with `arrange` to remind that dates should be in order.

Comment: Hi RLave, my data were already arranged this way. I probably should have mentioned that in the question. Thanks for the help!